# Lattice gauge theory with $A_\mu$ instead of $E_\mu$ or $B_\mu$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

In most formulations of the lattice gauge theory one uses the Hilbert space basis defined by the eigenstates of the electric or magnetic field. For example, in the "electric basis" on one uses electric field $E_\mu$ and link $U_\mu$ operators, which are canonically conjugated to each other.

I am wondering if there exist any lattice formulations of gauge theories in which one would work in the eigenbasis of the $A_\mu$ operators, and the Hilbert space would span the Fock states (defined on individual lattice sites). And if nobody does this — why?..

Comment: For compact U(1), the eigenbasis of $U_\mu$ is the same as the eigenbasis of $A_\mu$.

Comment: I believe you can do this, it just makes writing down gauge invariant operators difficult. Instead, you can write down "operatos that are gauge invariant in the limit of zero spacing", it would seem?